# Merge two SQL queries - unable to use WHERE clause with between option in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have these two SQL queries:

```
select * 
from table1 
where table1.item_no::character varying between '2000' and '3000' 
  and batch_id = 'new'
```

and

```
select * 
from table1 
where table1.item_no::int between '2000' and '3000' 
  and batch_id = 'new'
```

`item_no` datatype is character varying.

How to merge the above two SQL queries in postgres?

Comment: It's unclear your question.. Could you give some sample data and your desired result?

Comment: Why are you storing numbers in a `varchar` column to begin with? The second one should probably be `table1.item_no::int between 2000 and 3000`

Comment: It's totally unclear what you mean with "merge", but here are basic options: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-union.html

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name the secnd is  table1.item_no::int between 2000 and 3000.

Comment: @Ancoron .i have data  "1623H","1623I" in .item_no column so i want to join two queries.

Comment: No, it isn't. `'2000'` is a string value `2000` is a number, you shouldn't compare numbers with strings (and you should **not** store numbers in `varchar` columns)